# Routing across subnets

Tags: networking, routing, subnet

We have an IP phone system on a 172.16.x.x address. This is a live system which we use every day so we know it works.
The confusing part is; all the desk phones are on 172.16.1.x whereas the gateway is on 172.16.0.x
The phones are connected to a switch, the switch to the router and the router to the internet. That's it.

How is it possible that we're using two different subnets...?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you say they're two different subnets?

Comment: The subnet is defined by the subnet mask. What is it? If it is 255.255.0.0 then your network goes from 172.16.0.0 to 172.16.255.255

Comment: The mask is indeed 255.255.0.0 so this would make sense.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: I say two subnets because one is 172.16.0.x and the other is 172.16.1.x
As Class B addresses all have the host address of 172.16, the subnet is a logical and visible subdivision of the rest of the address.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork

Comment: @RichM So you confirmed their subnet masks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its a managed switch it would be possible the switch knows the route from 172.16.1.x to 172.16.0.x.

So when there goes a packet from one of the phones (from 172.16.1.x) the switch routes them to the 172.16.0.x network.

Same possibility with the router (i.e: the route is configured in the router, which routes all packets between the networks).

Comment: Having a smart switch with routingcapabilities or a real router would indeed allow this. But in this case the OP ahas added information in comment. The subnetmask is 255.255.0.0, which puts the whle range of 172.16.0.0 to 172.16.255.255 in a single subnet.

Comment: Yes, you're right. However the added information about the subnet ist clarifying the situation and could be the answer to this question as well.

Answer (score 2):

> The mask is indeed 255.255.0.0 so this would make sense.

You were thinking in an "old" classful system, modern networks use VLSM to have different sizes (2, 8, 16, 32...).

Your network would require at least /23 by the sounds of things, 255.255.254.0 which gives 2x the class C you have as an understanding of. Whoever deployed the network gave you a whole Class B in any case, probably because the whole network is small and they didn't bother conserving IP space. This gives you all 172.16.x.x which is 65536 addresses. Probably excessive but probably of no consequence.

Comment: 255.255.0.0 is a tad more than 512. (2^16=65536). So 65534 usable address, all i one single subnet.

Answer (score 0):

Well the netmask solution makes sense and the switch we're using is a Netgear GS748TP which I've had a look at but can't see any routing specifically geared towards this.

Thanks for all your answers!